# Execute a function only if a specific cell contains a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The below code works just great.
Now I only want it to function if cell `B2` says "2020".
If cell `B2` says "2021", for example, I want the value instead to go to sheet "2021".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim xRtn As Variant
     If Selection.Count = 1 Then
         If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D9:AS20")) Is Nothing Then
             xRtn = Application.InputBox("Insert your value please")
             Sheets("2020").Range(Target.Address).Value = xRtn           
         End If
     End If
End Sub
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved myself

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim xRta As Variant
     If Selection.Count = 1 Then
     If ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = "2020" Then
         If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D9:AS20")) Is Nothing Then
             xRta = Application.InputBox("Insert your value please")
             Sheets("2020").Range(Target.Address).Value = xRta
            End If
         End If
     End If

Dim xRtb As Variant
     If Selection.Count = 1 Then
     If ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = "2021" Then
         If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D9:AS20")) Is Nothing Then
             xRtb = Application.InputBox("Insert your value please")
             Sheets("2021").Range(Target.Address).Value = xRtb
            End If
         End If
     End If
End Sub
```